# send email codeigniter 3 not working localhost use wamppserver

Tags: email, codeigniter-3

```
 $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'easyfact');
$this->email->to('example@gmail.com');
$this->email->cc('example@gmail.com');
$this->email->bcc('example@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

reulst website

```
 Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

and

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

i use wamppserver helf me

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `$config` variable anywhere. Call

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

That should solve your problem.

See also: [Setting Email Preferences](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences) part of Codeigniter Email class documentation.

Comment: Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. v1sm128263817pgv.33 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: See this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972179/unable-to-send-email-using-php-mail-your-server-might-not-be-configured-to-se